# python facebook api in linux?

Tags: python, installation, facebook

How do i install package and libraries of facebook api? When i use
 `import facebook`, there's error?

I see only svn checkouts, some files are empty, how do i download and get them working?

Comment: Please clarify your question - at least include the error messages you get. We are not psychics.

Comment: You probably have to add the `facebook` package to your Python path.

Comment: Tamas: thanks, many modules are already there in python, so i was bit confused at that time.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have `git`, probably the easiest way to download it is to go to http://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook and click on the "Download source" button. Extract the downloaded ZIP to a subdirectory, enter that subdirectory, launch your Python interpreter and type `import facebook`. It works for me.

Comment: It says no module named django.conf. I have even installed django-simple-menu

Answer (score 1):

Start with the [tutorial](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User:PyFacebook_Tutorial), which leads you through the download (with `svn` or `git` on Linux or Windows), installation, desktop apps (including a simple session on the interactive Python interpreter), and so on.

Comment: Your link is broken, and I wasn't able to find a developer wiki.